# Computing $\mathrm{Tor}_{i}^{R/(ab)}(R/(a),R/(b))$

Tags: commutative-algebra, homological-algebra

Suppose $R$ is a UFD, and $a$ and $b$ are relatively prime. My calculation says that $\mathrm{Tor}_{i}^{R/(ab)}(R/(a),R/(b))$ is zero for all $i\neq 0$, which makes me suspicious. I begin be constructing a free resolution for $R/(a)$ in the following way

$$ \cdots \overset{\cdot a}{\longrightarrow}R/(ab)\overset{\cdot b}{\longrightarrow}R/(ab)\overset{\cdot a}{\longrightarrow}R/(ab)\longrightarrow R/(a)\longrightarrow0$$

Then we take the tensor with $R/(b)$. <s>By the Chinese remainder theorem...</s> We have immediately that $\mathrm{Tor}_0=R/(a)\otimes_{R/(ab)}R/(b)=R/(a,b)$.

Now, $R/(ab)\otimes_{R/(ab)}R/(b)\cong R/(b)$. Thus the resolution above becomes
$$ \cdots \overset{\cdot a}{\longrightarrow}R/(b)\overset{\cdot b}{\longrightarrow}R/(b)\overset{\cdot a}{\longrightarrow}R/(b)\longrightarrow R/(a,b) \longrightarrow0$$
<s>By the chinese remainder theorem again...</s> Taking the homology of the resulting sequence, the kernel of the map $R/(b)\longrightarrow R/(a,b)$ are cosets of the form $r+(b)$ with $r\in (a,b)$. Thus, $r\in(a)$ (or another representative of the same coset of $(b)$ is in $(a)$). This is precisely the image of the previous map, so $\mathrm{Tor}_1=0$. By the fact that $(a)$ and $(b)$ are coprime we have that $R/(b)\overset{\cdot a}{\longrightarrow}R/(b)$ is injective, and thus implies that all higher homology of this sequence is also zero. Am I missing something here? Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Chinese remainder theorem does not apply here.  To apply the Chinese remainder theorem to the ideals $(a)$ and $(b)$, you would need to know that $(a)+(b)$ is the whole ring $R$, which may not be the case (consider $R=k[x,y]$, $a=x$, $b=y$).

In general, multiplication by $a$ will be injective on $R/(b)$ (since $a$ and $b$ are relatively prime) but not surjective. So for even $i$, you will get that $\mathrm{Tor}_i^{R/(ab)}(R/(a),R/(b))$ is the cokernel of multiplication by $a$ on $R/(b)$, which is $R/(a,b)$.

Comment: Ah, so you are right. I was accidentally assuming $R$ was a PID I think.