# If $I \cap J = IJ$ are $\operatorname{Tor}_{i>0}(R/I, R/J) =0$?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, homological-algebra

Let $I$ and $J$ be ideals in commutative ring $R$, or more generally sheaves of ideals on a scheme. Tensoring the short exact sequence 
$$
0\to I \to R \to R/I \to 0
$$
by $R/J$ it's easy to see that $\operatorname{Tor}_{1}(R/I, R/J) \cong (I \cap J)/IJ$. So if I assume that $I \cap J = IJ$ then $\operatorname{Tor}_{1}(R/I, R/J)=0$. Is it true that higher Tor's also vanish? That is,

> $\operatorname{Tor}_{i>1}(R/I, R/J)=0$ when $I \cap J = IJ$?

Comment: Have you googled rigidity of Tor? In particular, a famous example of Dutta-Hochster? I think it is relevant.

Comment: @Mohan: Depending on the asker's background, they might have no idea about that until being informed of it by you - remember, this is MSE, not MO. (They might not even know what "rigidity of Tor" means!) I think it would be very helpful if you wrote what you were talking about as an answer.

Comment: I do not have much to say other than what can generally be found out there. An old question in this direction is, if $M,N$ are finitely generated modules over a Noetherian local ring $R$ and $\mathrm{Tor}^1_R(M,N)=0$, does it imply all higher Tors vanish. This is called the rigidity of Tor. It is known in some cases, but a counterexample was found by Dutta-Hochster in this generality.

Comment: This question has a (negative) answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2396057/computing-mathrmtor-ir-abr-a-r-b).